# Jquery input checkbox & radio - not working

Tags: jquery

I tried to style my checkbox and radio input with jquery/html/css but it isn't working.

**The radio is not working.**

What changes can I make to make it work?

Thanks a lot !

[ I am aware that I can do it with css3 via the ' + label ' but for some reasons that won't work out. I like this jquery one because if it is disable it still works perfecty on browsers ]

This is the code:

modification of ( http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/customInput.jquery.js )

```
jQuery.fn.customInput = function(){
$(this).each(function(i){   
    if($(this).is('input:checkbox,input:radio')){
        var input = $(this);

        // get the associated label using the input's id
        var label = input.next();

        // wrap the input + label in a div 
        var wrapper = $("<div/>");
        if (input.is(':checkbox')) {
            wrapper.addClass("custom-checkbox");
        }
        else {
            wrapper.addClass("custom-radio");
        }
        wrapper.insertBefore(input).append(input, label);

        // necessary for browsers that don't support the :hover pseudo class on labels
        label.hover(
            function(){ 
                if (!this.disabled) {
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                } 
            },
            function(){ 
                $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
            } 
        );

        //bind custom event and trigger it, then bind click,focus,blur events                   
        input.bind('updateState', function(){   
            label.toggleClass("disabled", input.is(":disabled"));
            if (input.is(':checked')) {
                if (input.is(':radio')) {
                    $('input[name='+input.attr('name')+']').each(function(){
                        $('label[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').removeClass('checked');
                    });     
                }
                label.addClass('checked');
            }
            else { 
                label.removeClass('checked');
            }
        })
        .trigger('updateState')
        .click(function(){ 
            $(this).trigger('updateState'); 
        })
        .focus(function(){ 
            label.addClass('focus'); 
        })
        .blur(function(){ label.removeClass('focus '); });
    }
});
```

};

The demo -> http://jsbin.com/uyateb/2/edit

Comment: Sorry but what is it you''re trying to do, ie style it how?

Comment: Looks quite re-styled to me!

Comment: the radio input is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the javascript console of your browser. It is your friend.

In your example I see an error telling me

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=option[218]]
```

that is caused by this expression

```
$('input[name='+input.attr('name')+']')
```

If the name value is different from a simple name (in your case it is `option[218]`) then you have to use extra quotes around the value. So change your code to

```
$('input[name="'+input.attr('name')+'"]')
```

and the error is gone.